# How to remove duplicates array in multidimensional array where the key positions might not same in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
let originalArray = [
  ["A", "B", "C"],
  ["B", "A", "C"],
  ["D", "E", "F"]
];

let uniqueArray = originalArray.filter((item, index, self) => { 
    return index === self.findIndex((t) => JSON.stringify(t) === JSON.stringify(item)); 
}); 

console.log(uniqueArray);
```

I want this result:

```
[
 ["A", "B", "C"],
 ["D", "E", "F"]
];
```

To remove duplicates from a multidimensional array in JavaScript, where the key positions might not be the same, you can use a combination of **`Array.prototype.map()`**, **`Array.prototype.filter()`**, and **`Array.prototype.includes()`** to create a new array with only unique elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object with Array.prototype.reduce, storing a stringified version of the sorted values as the cache.

```js
let originalArray = [
  ["A", "B", "C"],
  ["B", "A", "C"],
  ["D", "E", "F"]
];

let uniqueArray = Object.values(originalArray.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const data = [...cur].sort();
    const key = JSON.stringify(data);
    acc[key] = acc[key] ?? cur;
    return acc; 
}, {})); 

console.log(uniqueArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can `sort` the inner arrays before inserting them into a `Set` for filtering.

```js
let originalArray = [
  ["A", "B", "C"],
  ["B", "A", "C"],
  ["D", "E", "F"]
];
let vis = new Set;
let res = originalArray.filter(x => {
  const str = JSON.stringify([...x].sort());
  return !vis.has(str) && vis.add(str);
});
console.log(res);
```